# Reconnect using retryWhen with two different delay

Tags: java, redis, rx-java2

I want to have **two** types of retry connection with different delay (I use Redis running on Kubernetes and jedis clinet).
It is possible to do it like this, and use `retryWhen` two times in the same block? If not, how to do it? A unit tests provide me, that is not working correctly (I think only first `retryWhen` is called, but second not). Where is the bug?

```
public Observable<String> getMessagesFromChannel(String channel) {
  return PublishSubject.<String>fromPublisher(
        subscriber ->
                config.executor().execute(() -> 
                bindRedisSubscriptionToPublisher(channel,subscriber)))
        .retryWhen(t -> t.take(config.numberOfReconnectWhenNetworkIsBreak()).delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
        .doOnError(ex -> 
    log.trace("Trying to subscribe " + config.numberOfReconnect() + " times without success"))
        .retryWhen(
        ts -> ts.doOnEach(
                ex -> {
                  log.warn(
                      "Redis instance down. Error while subscribing, trying to reconnect in {} ms",
                      config.reconnectTimeAfterRedisInstanceDown().toMillis(),
                      ex.getValue());
                })
       .delay(config.reconnectTimeAfterRedisInstanceDown().toMillis(), MILLISECONDS, config.scheduler()));
 }
```

Comment: > I want to have two types of retry connection -- Could you please be more specific? Please describe in words how your retry-strategy should work.

Comment: ok, so because of break network connection I want to retry 5 times with 1 sec delay without any log tracing, but if I have still no connection to the redis instances, I want to add a warning and retry again with 10 sec delay because I hope is a situation when Redis is setup again by kubernetes

Comment: Ok I got it. Let's have a look what we can do